# calling method with two object and store in array of objects

Tags: c#

I want to call a method where two parametres are objects (one retrieve Person, one added Person). Then store in array of Person objects and then I can work with both object separatelly.

In method:
I do create object Person and store data in it from retrieve data from database where firstName is "Mediterranean".
And add other row(Person features) and do want to pass it back as well.
But doesn't return objects and straight fail.

Can somebody help me please?

I have something like this:

```
public Person [] retrievePerson(Person somePerson, Person addRowPerson)
{ 
    .......
    findedPerson = new Person(title, firstName, secondName, city, nationality, letter);
    myTableCreatedPerson = new Person(title, firstName, secondName, city, nationality, letter);
    return retrievePerson(findedPerson, myTableCreatedPerson);
}

//and calling function in different class like that
public void retrievePersonTest() //Create Person in DB directly then Retrieve Person and compare retrieve features with create features then directly delete him from DB
{               
    Person expected = null;
    Person actual = null;
    Person addRowPerson = null;
    Person [] twoPersonArray;
    DBConnect target = new DBConnect();

    try //retrieve Person
    {                    
        twoPersonArray =  target.retrievePerson(expected, addRowPerson); //do not return                  
        twoPersonArray = (Func<Person, Person>)target.retrievePerson(expected, addRowPerson).CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<Person, Person>)); //do not return either
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created an endless recursion, because at the end of `retrievePerson` you are calling it again.

You need to change the return statement of `retrievePerson` to this:

```
return new[] {findedPerson, myTableCreatedPerson};
```

Comment: Thanks you Daniel working perfectly now. I like this idea that someone can help another...hope in future i can do the same. Have you got idea where I can found resources and learn ADO.net or recommend good book.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear why you pass parameter, if you don't use it after in the functions, but *suppose* it's a mistake

```
public Person [] retrievePerson(Person somePerson = null, Person addRowPerson = null)
{ 
     bool nullpassed = false;

       if(somePerson  == null) {
          nullpassed  = true;
          somePerson  = new Person(title, firstName, secondName, city, nationality, letter);
       }

       if(addRowPerson == null) {
          nullpassed = true;
          addRowPerson = new Person(title, firstName, secondName, city, nationality, letter);
       }

       if(nullpassed)    
           return retrievePerson(somePerson  , addRowPerson );
       else 
           return new Person[] {somePerson  , addRowPerson} 
}
```

This **should** work, but you need to test this.

But I also **strongly** recommend revise your code, and use distinct functions for every operation you make. Do not make double calls to the same function that *behaves* differently. You're going to jump into the complete mess some months later, when the code will become more and more complex.

Hope this helps.